# Is it problem with parsing/instantiating templates in VS2010?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

Please don't mind the length of this code (just copy and paste). When you do it run it and it won't compile under VS2010. In order to compile this code, in struct Range remove "class IntType," from template parameters and in main instead of:

```
Range<int,float> r;
```

make

```
Range<float> r; //int is removed
```

Code:

```
template<class T>
struct Assign_Low_High
{
    static const int low_value = 0;
};


//in order to compile remove class IntType, from template params of Range struct
template<class IntType, class L>
struct Range
{
    static_assert(Assign_Low_High<L>::low_value < 1,
                    "Incorrect Range");
};


int main()
{
    //in order to compile remove int from Range
    Range<int,float> r;
    return 0;
}
```

What on earth is going on? (it does compile with GCC 4.5.1).

Comment: Could you make an effort to reduce the code snippet to the *minimum* required to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: @Oli that's the minimum. Just copy and paste. Copy from place marked //copy from here to place marked //to here

Comment: @There: That's a lot of code to wade through.  Are you saying you can't possibly simplify it in any further?

Comment: @Oli to your question yes, that's the bare minimum AFAIC, but you don't have to look through this code, concentrate on **Range** struct.

Comment: @There: If the rest of the code is *required*, then clearly it's not necessarily a matter of concentrating on that single struct!

Comment: @Oli did you try to run it?!!! If yes, then you'll see for yourself that the only place where you should look at is Range struct!!!

Comment: @There: Yes, I did.  And that's clearly not true, all the other code must have an impact.  I'm currently stripping out code; I wish you would try the same!

Comment: @Oli I've did my best before I've posted this question to remove everything what I could in order to demonstrate it. What I've posted I've thought it's a bare minimum.

Comment: @There: I've taken the liberty of editing your question to include a much smaller code snippet that demonstrates the problem.  Let me know if you agree with it...

Comment: @Oli yes, thank you, as long as the semantics are as they were I'm more than happy to have less code.

Comment: @There: Well, it's nowhere near the same as your original code, but I think it illustrates the same problem with removing the first template parameter.

Comment: @Oli ok, so is there any verdict on what's going on there?

Comment: @There: However, I spotted that if you change the `<` comparison operator to any other operator (e.g. `==` or `>`), the syntax error disappears.

Comment: @Oli it looks like "great" VS team screwed up... again. You, know what, is there any new (C++11) feature which they've implemented correctly? To me it seems that there isn't. decltype - messed up (myself posted good few bug reports on Connect), static_assert - screwed up (it looks like anyway), lambda - screwed up - I'm sorry but they are just unprofessional in their approach.

Comment: Remember that the C++0x standard was not finalized when VS 2010 was released, much less while it was in development. The team worked with what they had. It's a fair bet that the next version will be fully compliant. It's not terribly productive to slam the entire development team as "unprofessional". If you don't like Visual Studio (and you apparently don't), please consider one of the alternatives. There are lots of good choices. (A good question, though; +1 from me.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it looks like the < operator throws the compiler off the wrong track. If you:

```
static_assert( Assign_Low_High<L>::low_value > -1, "Incorrect Range");
```

or

```
static_assert( (Assign_Low_High<L>::low_value) < 1, "Incorrect Range");
```

it will work.

If you do:

```
static_assert( Assign_Low_High<L>::low_value < 1 > 0, "Incorrect Range");
```

then it gets interesting...

I think the compiler should consider the low_value dependent name to be a non type non template dependent name and consider the "<" following low_value to be the less than operator. So I would say the gcc compiler does the right thing while the MS 2010 compiler does not, but fortunately it can be helped to produce the desired effect.

One more thing, this is obviously not due to the static_assert since:

```
 bool bComp = Assign_Low_High<int>::low_value < 1;
```

directly in main leads to the same compile errors...

Answer (score 0):

I can't compile that right now, but it looks like its your static_assert thats failing. You're asserting that low value is less than 0, when it is actually equal to 0.

If thats not the problem, would you mind posting the compiler error ?

*EDIT*
Moving the static assert to the constructor of Range compiles properly, and still accomplishes the goal of asserting whenever you use the template. Based on this, and the fact that the clause in the assert compiles when not in an assert, I would assume that MS's static_assert implementation is a bit buggy.

Comment: @Kindread: I've simplified @There's code snippet, so it doesn't necessarily make a lot of sense as it stands.  The problem is not the failure of the `static_assert`, VS2010 complains of a syntax error.

Comment: Well, its possible that static_assert is buggy, since it was added with the latest standard. Possibly MS's implementation is actually a macro that references that class type, and it is getting confused. Sorry I know thats not very helpful. You could try moving the static_assert to a different scope ( maybe the struct constructor ), which could possibly fix it. I'm just taking a guess that that will solve it, at least until someone has a better answer...

Comment: @Kindread thank you for your time. Yes, it looks like they messed up this feature too. And I remember how Stephan Lavatvei (or something like this) boasted that someone from VS team implemented static_assert in half a day. Well, that's what happens when you implement something within half a day. God almighty, VS is such a pathetic lot.

Comment: I'd be interested to know if moving the assert to a method's scope helped. I don't have a compiler available at the moment to try it out. If it did then I think it proves its a static_assert bug.

Comment: @Kindread how would you go about it? Place static_assert in fnc and call this fnc?

Comment: what I had in mind was giving Range a constructor and asserting in there. ie : 

template<class IntType, class L>
struct Range
{
    static_assert(Assign_Low_High<L>::low_value < 1,
                    "Incorrect Range");

    Range()
    {
      static_assert....
    }
};

Comment: @Kindread with static_assert inside ctor it works. So it looks like it's buggy static_assert, would you agree with me?

Comment: Based on that a buggy static_assert is the only explanation i have as well.

Comment: @Kindread I'm going to submit this on Connect but knowing their approach this will be resolved to either not reproducible or by design ;)

Comment: @ds27680 Sorry but I can't make comments on your post yet so I put it here. I just tried out putting your code snippet in main and it did in fact compile. Did you remember to remove the assert from the struct when you tried it out ?